# Confirm password is empty in EditText in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, confirm, is-empty

Here are my methods to 1st, enter a new password, and 2nd, to confirm the password.

```
public void editPassword(){

    AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    d.setTitle("New password");

    // Set up the input
    final EditText newPassword = new EditText(this);
    // Specify the type of input expected as a password
    newPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    d.setView(newPassword);

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"new password: " + newPassword.getText().toString());
    final Editable changedPassword = newPassword.getText();

    // Set up the buttons
    d.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            confirmPassword(changedPassword);
        }
    });
    d.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    d.show();


}
public void confirmPassword(final Editable password){
    AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    d.setTitle("Confirm password");

    // Set up the input
    final EditText confirmPassword = new EditText(this);
    // Specify the type of input expected as a password
    confirmPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    d.setView(confirmPassword);

    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"Password: " + password.toString());
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"Confirm password: " + confirmPassword.getText().toString());
    final Editable confirm = confirmPassword.getText();

    // Set up the buttons
    d.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(password.equals(confirm)){
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords match ");
                //TODO send new password to database
            }
            else{
                //TODO dialog/toast saying "passwords don't match"
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords don't match ");
                confirmPassword(password);
            }

        }
    });
    d.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    d.show();

}
```

In the first method, `editPassword()`, the password is correctly stored in the variable `changedPassword`, and it is correctly passed to `confirmPassword(changedPassword)`.

HOWEVER in the method `confirmPassword()`, the variable `confirm` is empty after the assignment `final Editable confirm = confirmPassword.getText();`

whats happening?? what am i missing here? i cant see the thing and it must be sth "stupid". Please, any help? Thx

Comment: can you try this  confirmPassword(confirmPassword.getText()); instead of  confirmPassword(changedPassword); Although this would not make much of difference but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
    d.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Editable confirm = confirmPassword.getText();
        if(password.equals(confirm)){
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords match ");
            //TODO send new password to database
        }
        else{
            //TODO dialog/toast saying "passwords don't match"
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords don't match ");
            confirmPassword(password);
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: You should call confirmPassword.getText(); inside click event that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Editable.toString` which *returns a string with the same characters in the same order as in this sequence.*  like :

**First Option:**

```
if(password.equals(confirm.toString())){
     Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords match "); 
  }
  else{
    ....
  }
```

**Second Option:**

Get `Editable` object from `password` as:

```
      Editable editablePassword = new SpannableStringBuilder(password);
      if(editablePassword.equals(confirm)){
         Log.d(DEBUG_TAG1,"passwords match "); 
      }
      else{
        ....
      }
```